# VBA Check if variable is empty

Tags: vba, object, variables, is-empty

I have an object and within it I want to check if some properties are set to `False`, like:

```vb
If (Not objresult.EOF) Then
  'Some code 
End if
```

But sometimes, `objresult.EOF` is `Empty`; how can I check for this?

- `IsEmpty` function is for excel cells only
- `objresult.EOF Is Nothing` - returns `Empty`
- `objresult.EOF <> null` - returns `Empty` as well!

Comment: Please provide some real code - show us what type of object is `objresult`. And `IsEmpty` is not specific for excel cells, it is for `Variant` variables.

Answer (score 110):

How you test depends on the Property's DataType:

```
| Type                                 | Test                            | Test2
| Numeric (Long, Integer, Double etc.) | If obj.Property = 0 Then        | 
| Boolen (True/False)                  | If Not obj.Property Then        | If obj.Property = False Then
| Object                               | If obj.Property Is Nothing Then |
| String                               | If obj.Property = "" Then       | If LenB(obj.Property) = 0 Then
| Variant                              | If obj.Property = Empty Then    |
```

You can tell the DataType by pressing F2 to launch the Object Browser and looking up the Object. Another way would be to just use the TypeName function:`MsgBox TypeName(obj.Property)`

Comment: `obj.Property = Empty` works for Numeric values as well.

Comment: I tried it with an unset worksheets variable. A check was only possible like this: `If ws Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Thanks Axel. This applies to Workbook variables too.

Comment: @Axel did not work for me for a workbook var: if var is empty then it throws a runtime error 424 `object needed`.

Answer (score 23):

To check if a `Variant` is Null, you need to do it like:

```
Isnull(myvar) = True
```

or

```
Not Isnull(myvar)
```

Answer (score 13):

For a number, it is tricky because if a numeric cell is `empty` VBA will assign a default value of 0 to it, so it is hard for your VBA code to tell the difference between an entered zero and a blank numeric cell.

The following check worked for me to see if there was an actual 0 entered into the cell:

```
If CStr(rng.value) = "0" then
    'your code here'
End If
```

Comment: Your code sample is a great workaround for distinguishing 0 and Empty

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue with an integer that could be legitimately assigned 0 in Access VBA. None of the above solutions worked for me.

**At first I just used a boolean var and IF statement:**

```
Dim i as integer, bol as boolean
   If bol = false then
      i = ValueIWantToAssign
      bol = True
   End If
```

In my case, my integer variable assignment was within a for loop and another IF statement, so I ended up using "Exit For" instead as it was more concise.

**Like so:**

```
Dim i as integer
ForLoopStart
   If ConditionIsMet Then
      i = ValueIWantToAssign
   Exit For
   End If
ForLoopEnd
```