# Check length of Variant object

Tags: vba

I want to find out if there are any elements in a list after applying filter to it. The list is of type variant which seems to be a problem. Most suggestions are in line with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329110/vba-check-if-variable-is-empty): but it does not work for me. What am i doing wrong?

```
Dim message As Variant
Dim tempMessage As Variant
Dim a As Long
message = Split("AACP;CP;sBcp;ccffcp", ";")
tempMessage = Filter(message, "CP", False, vbTextCompare)
If IsNull(tempMessage) = True Then
    Debug.Print "EMPTY"
Else
    Debug.Print tempMessage(0)
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a couple of ways:

1. `VarType(tempMessage)` will be `vbEmpty` if it is completely blank.
2. `VarType(tempMessage) And vbArray` will be non-zero if it's an array type (even with zero elements. Zero length arrays *are* allowed in VBA). Here I'm using `And` in the *logical* context.

If you've established it's an array, then you can take a guess at the dimensionality. (VBA provides no function for this, but luckily you should know from the documentation of `Filter`).

If you've established the variant is an array then use `UBound(tempMessage) - LBound(tempMessage) + 1` to get the number of elements.

Comment: VarType(tempMessage) returns 8200 and UBound(tempMessage) - UBound(tempMessage) + 1 returns 1 always, even if there are no items...

Comment: 8200 is vbArray + vbString so is therefore an array type. Do you know what I mean when I say *logical* `And`?

Comment: No I dont :(
I this check seems to work: If UBound(tempMessage) > -1 Then

Comment: I think you mean:
UBound(tempMessage) - LBound(tempMessage) + 1

Comment: @hayder Oops yes I did. Thanks. Btw always feel feee to male such edits yourself.