# array push - Write a VBA function that accepts any type of array

Tags: arrays, vba, types

I'm trying to write a simple `push` function that can add an element to my VBA arrays.

I can't figure out how to allow it to accept typed arrays.  So far, I can get the function to accept arrays explicitly typed as "Variant".  See below

```
Function push(arr() As Variant, el As Variant) As Variant()
    ' function to redim an array and increment it by one.  If array is length 1 and element is empty, it will place the "el" param in the first index
    If IsEmpty(arr(UBound(arr))) And UBound(arr) = LBound(arr) Then
        arr(UBound(arr)) = el
    Else
        ReDim Preserve arr(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) + 1)
        arr(UBound(arr)) = el
    End If
    push = arr
End Function

Sub testPush()
    Dim myArr() As Variant
    Dim newArr() As Variant
    myArr = Array("apple", "banana", "4")
    myArr = push(myArr, "coconut")
    Debug.Print Join(myArr, ", ")
    newArr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    newArr = push(newArr, 7)
    Debug.Print Join(newArr, ", ")
End Sub
```

When I dimension myArr as string, e.g., `Dim myArr() as String` I see a compile error in my push function: `Type mismatch: array or user defined type expected`.  Is there any way I can use a single function that attempts to increment an element to the end of an array, regardless of the array type?

Comment: Side note: I think you can reduce to _If IsEmpty(arr(UBound(arr))) And UBound(arr) = LBound(arr)_  to  _If Not UBound(arr) And IsEmpty(arr(UBound(arr)))_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to what I write below, maybe someone who knows more than me will tell you this is possible and exactly how you can do this.

---

I see that your function returns an array of variants:

```
Function push(arr() As Variant, el As Variant) As Variant()
```

which, if I understand correctly, can only be assigned to a variable of type `Variant` or `Variant()`.

If I change the function to:

```
Function push(arr As Variant, el As Variant) As Variant
```

I think the function can now accept an array of any type<sup>1</sup> but it still returns a `Variant` -- which I believe can't be assigned to every typed array (meaning you'll still get a compiler error in some cases).

What might be an easier approach is to change the `Function` to a `Sub` and have the subroutine modify the array in-place. That way there is no assignment at the call site (since subroutines do not return values) and the code should compile. This also means any type error<sup>2</sup> will now occur at run-time.

Also, it's not clear to me what the point of the below is:

```
If IsEmpty(arr(UBound(arr)))
```

It seems like you're checking if the array's first element has been assigned something other than its default initialised value. But that check seems like it will only work for `Variant` types (which are initialised as empty). I think strings are initialised as `""`, numbers are initialised as `0`, objects are initialised as `Nothing`, and so on. In short, I think the `IsEmpty` check may return false negative for types other than `Variant`. The aforementioned behaviour might be what you want, or it might not be (given that you say you want this `Push` code to work with arrays of any type).

Overall, one approach could be something like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Push(ByRef someArray As Variant, ByVal someElement As Variant)
    ' This routine expects array to be 1-dimensional.
    ' and will modify the array in-place.
    ' The array must by dynamic (cannot Redim an array that
    ' was statically declared).

    Dim lastIndex As Long
    lastIndex = UBound(someArray)

    Dim arrayNeedsExtending As Boolean
    ' If you are using "IsEmpty" to work out if the first element
    ' has been assigned a value other than its default value at initialisation
    ' then you may need to see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3331239/8811778
    ' as "IsEmpty" might only work for Variants and may return false
    ' negatives otherwise.
    arrayNeedsExtending = (lastIndex <> LBound(someArray)) Or Not IsEmpty(someArray(lastIndex))

    If arrayNeedsExtending Then
        ReDim Preserve someArray(LBound(someArray) To (lastIndex + 1))
    End If

    ' If you have an array of objects (hypothetically, instead of a collection), the line below
    ' will raise a syntax error since Set keyword is required for objects.
    someArray(UBound(someArray)) = someElement
End Sub

Private Sub TestPush()

    Dim someStrings() As String
    someStrings = Split("a,a", ",", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
    Push someStrings, "b"
    Debug.Assert (JoinArray(someStrings) = "a,a,b")

    Dim someBooleans() As Boolean ' Can only Push dynamic arrays
    ReDim someBooleans(0 To 1)
    Push someBooleans, True
    Debug.Assert (JoinArray(someBooleans) = "False,False,True")

    Dim someZeros() As Long
    ReDim someZeros(0 To 1)
    Push someZeros, 0
    Debug.Assert (JoinArray(someZeros) = "0,0,0")

End Sub

Private Function JoinArray(ByRef someArray As Variant, Optional delimiter As String = ",") As String
    ' Expects array to be 1-dimensional.
    ' Attempts to handle non-string types albeit without error handling.

    Dim toJoin() As String
    ReDim toJoin(LBound(someArray) To UBound(someArray))

    Dim arrayIndex As Long
    For arrayIndex = LBound(someArray) To UBound(someArray)
        toJoin(arrayIndex) = CStr(someArray(arrayIndex)) ' Will throw if type cannot be coerced into string.
    Next arrayIndex

    JoinArray = Join(toJoin, delimiter)
End Function
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Maybe not user-defined types though.

<sup>2</sup> Say you pass the string`"a"` to be pushed into a `Long`-typed array -- or any value that cannot be type-coerced into the array's type.